# How do I remove paint from plastic window frames?

Tags: painting, paint

The paint is dark red and has dried. It only covers little areas on the plastic of the window frame.

How do I remove it without damaging the frame?

The frames are white.

Answer (score 1):

Goof Off 2 is made for removing paint from plastics.

Comment: Do you have any evidence to back up this claim?

Comment: Only that I use it all the time for removing paint from plastics or where I'm afraid the full-strength Goof Off would be too caustic.  Always try in a hidden or small place first.  Hope this helps.  I've been very lucky with this stuff so far--no problems yet.

Answer (score 0):

I've had good results with rubbing alcohol or ammonia.